# How to save updated value from field after event in JEditable/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

Now my page containts set of fields and JEditable script for editing:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>
    <div id="load-button" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:white;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;width:200px;text-align:center;border-radius:4px;">Load button</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function() {
          $(".field").editable("echo.php", { 
                indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
                tooltip   : "Move mouseover to edit...",
                event     : "mouseover",
                style  : "inherit"
          });  
        });
    </script>
    <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','') or die('connect');
        mysql_select_db('jquery_test') or die('select_db');
        $query=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM labels');
        while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            echo '<b class="field" style="display: inline">'.$data['text'].'</b><br >';
        }
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work properly: when I click by field, input new value and press "enter" then the field changes his value to "Click to edit", but I need that fields continue to show updated value. How can I do it? What should I change?

Comment: Also, please, tell me, can I return value from PHP script?

Comment: Please show us the final HTML generated using php.

Answer (score 0):

In you jQuery code I have something like this  - it's the .fnUpdate that really is the key part...

```
var tableElement = $(".field");
tableElement.editable("echo.php", { 
            style : "inherit",
            "callback": function(sValue,y){

                    //Grab the cell position
                    var aPos = tableElement.fnGetPosition(this);
                    tableElement.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
            },{

              "submitdata" : "OK"
 });

 tableElement.fnDraw();
```